# Docker is not running when trying to curl laravel

Tags: laravel, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, laravel-9

I am trying to set up Docker and Laravel 9 (both for the first time) on my Windows 10 system by following the [instructions](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x#getting-started-on-windows) on the official Laravel website.

I have successfully installed `Docker Doesktop` and have also successfully installed and activated Windows Subsystem for Linux 2 (WSL2).

I then installed Windows Terminal, connect to an Ubuntu 22.04 container that I have started and tried to run the following command as instructed on the official Laravel website:

```
curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash
```

But instead of creating a new project `example-app`, I get the following message instead:

```
Docker is not running.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The [script you reference](https://laravel.build/example-app) checks for Docker via `docker info`.  What does running that manually show?  Immediately after running it, run `echo $?`  What is the status code?  If it returns any status code other than 0, the script will abort with that message.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds docker info returns: `bash: docker: command not found` and immediately running `echo $?` returns `127`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I finally figured it out. When I open **Windows Terminal**, I need to first run `wsl` and then go forward with curl-ing Laravel and using it.

So after installing and activating WSL2 in Windows & Docker Desktop, the steps to follow would be:

1. In your terminal, run `wsl`.
2. Run the `curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash` command.
3. `cd` to the the new Laravel application `example-app` directory and then use Laravel Sail to run it.

Comment: so we can't download laravel in a Docker container? Because this will download and create the project in WSL distro. What if I download the official Ubuntu image from Docker Hub, run it as a container. Can I download Laravel in that container?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue (Mint Linux) that was driving me nuts (a short trip, to be fair).

```
curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash
```

replied with "**Docker is not running**" (it was/is).

I could run the curl command with sudo, but then other permissions issues would quickly arise...

Endless issues with permissons/user not working correctly. None of the myriad of suggestions on the Great Google helped.

I finally got it to work, by "Reset to factory defaults" in Docker Desktop, under Settings -> troubleshoot. Go figure.

Hope this helps someone else out there, who like me, isn't an utter guru in everything "geek".

[image]

Cheers, Chris